# Liquid Layout with 3 Columns

Tags: css

I am working on this website, and I am having some trouble with the columns. Right now there is a border around each column, which is the effect I want. However, I want them to be the same height. I understand the columns take the height of the tallest, but is there anyway to keep them the same throughout. I tried putting a container around each column separately, but I just could not get it to work. Any suggestions of how to accomplish this?

Here is the site: http://www.pitt.edu/~mkm49/1052/liquid.html

Answer (score 0):

You need a "clearfix" ... after all the columns .. like this ...

`<div class="clearfix"></div>`

.clearfix { clear: both; }

here you can find more on a subject [What methods of ‘clearfix’ can I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best)

Answer (score 0):

There there I got yo answer bro because I had the same issue myself a month ago... Well here's the answer:

CSS part

```
  .col {
   float:left;
   margin-left:3%;
   width:20%;
   height:300px;
   border-radius:10px;
   border-style:solid;
   border-width:5px
   }
```

Html part

```
  <div class="col">
    <p>Lorem...</p>
  </div

  <div class="col">
    <p>Lorem...</p>
  </div

  <div class="col">
    <p>Lorem...</p>
  </div
```

Should work cuz that is was I use ^_^